# Remove counter from mini cart if there is no product in the cart

Tags: magento2, frontend, mini-cart, porto-theme, porto

I have a smart wave Porto theme, I want to remove the counter (in red) from the mini cart like this if there is no product in the cart

[image]

If there is a product in the cart, then this will show like this

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fast method to conceal the counter is by using CSS. You can simply apply this CSS, and the counter will not be visible when the cart is empty.

```
.minicart-wrapper span.counter.qty.empty {
    display: none;
}
```